# Navigate with location.href during XMLHttpRequest asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I have a web page containing something like this:

```
<div onclick="location.href = 'AnotherPage';">
```

This page also uses asynchronous XMLHttpRequests for some ajax updating.

I have found that while an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest is in progress, clicking on this div does not load the new page. If I cancel my request first then it works fine. This seems wrong, but I cannot find any documentation that describes what *should* happen.

So the question is: what should happen to asynchronous XMLHttpRequests in progress when a new page is loaded using location.href?

*edit - I worked around this problem by handling window.onbeforeunload and aborting my pending async request there. The question remains though, whether I should need to do this?*

Answer (score 0):

You might check out a similar question:

[Browser waits for ajax call to complete even after abort has been called (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941889/browser-waits-for-ajax-call-to-complete-even-after-abort-has-been-called-jquery)

I also saw a few questions where browser history issues were arising in similar circumstances, and the workaround was to wrap the location change in a `setTimeout()` call with `0` delay. If that were to fix the behavior, I'd be baffled as to the reasoning, but it'd be interesting to see the effect nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks I did see that, but in the answer the asker states that the reason was server-side.

I think if I was going to wrap all my location changes then I might as well just call a function that could also cancel the requests.