# What are the implications/consequences of the AjaxPro HttpSessionStateRequirement?

Tags: ajax, ajaxpro

I know the different options (None, ReadWrite, Read) and what they mean, but are there any other implications? Does ReadWrite take a performance hit compared to None, for example? Are there other consequences, or things to keep in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed Michael Schwarz, who wrote AjaxPro, and got the following reply:

> Well, the main reason for adding this
>   attribute was to get rid of blocking
>   http requests. If you are accessing
>   session state variables in two
>   requests the 2nd one will need to wait
>   until the first one is finished. Since
>   I have added this attribute value I
>   always use
>   HttpSessionStateRequirement.None.
>
> For more details see:
>
> - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx
> - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate%28VS.80%29.aspx
> - [Browser waits for ajax call to complete even after abort has been called (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941889/browser-waits-for-ajax-call-to-complete-even-after-abort-has-been-called-jquery)